# In Scrapy, how to extract two groups in a regular expression into two different fields?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm writing a spider `trulia` to scrape pages of properties for sale on Trulia.com such as https://www.trulia.com/property/1072559047-1860-Lombard-St-San-Francisco-CA-94123; the current version can be found on https://github.com/khpeek/trulia-scraper.

I'm using [Item Loaders](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) and invoking the [add_xpath](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#scrapy.loader.ItemLoader.add_xpath) method with the `re` keyword argument to specify regular expressions to extract. In the example in the documentation, there is just one group in the regular expression and one field to extract to.

However, I would actually like to define two groups and extract them to two separate Scrapy fields. Here is an 'excerpt' from the `parse_property_page` method:

```
def parse_property_page(self, response):
    l = TruliaItemLoader(item=TruliaItem(), response=response)

    details = l.nested_css('.homeDetailsHeading')
    overview = details.nested_xpath('.//span[contains(text(), "Overview")]/parent::div/following-sibling::div[1]')
    overview.add_xpath('overview', xpath='.//li/text()')
    overview.add_xpath('area', xpath='.//li/text()', re=r'([\d,]+) sqft$')
    overview.add_xpath('lot_size', xpath='.//li/text()', re=r'([\d,]+) (acres|sqft) lot size$')
```

Notice how the `lot_size` field has two groups extracted: one for the number, and one for the units which can be either 'acres' or 'sqft'. If I run this `parse` method using the command

```
scrapy parse https://www.trulia.com/property/1072559047-1860-Lombard-St-San-Francisco-CA-94123 --spider=trulia --callback=parse_property_page
```

then I get the following scraped item:

```
# Scraped Items  ------------------------------------------------------------
[{'address': '1860 Lombard St',
  'area': 2524.0,
  'city_state': 'San Francisco, CA 94123',
  'dates': ['10/22/2002', '04/25/2002', '03/20/2000'],
  'description': ['Outstanding investment opportunity to own this light-fixer '
                  'mixed use Marina 2-unit property w/established income and '
                  'not on liquefaction. The first floor of this building '
                  'houses a commercial business currently leased to Jigalin '
                  'Fitness until 2018. The second floor presents a 2bed/1bath '
                  'apartment fully outfitted in a contemporary design w/full '
                  'kitchen, 10ft high ceilings & laundry area. The apartment '
                  'will be delivered vacant. The structure has undergone '
                  'renovation & features concrete perimeter foundation, '
                  'reinforced walls, ADA compliant commercial restroom, '
                  'electrical updates & rolling door. This property makes an '
                  "ideal investment with instant cash flow. Don't let this "
                  'pass you by. As-Is sale.'],
  'events': ['Sold', 'Sold', 'Sold'],
  'listing_information': ['2 Bedrooms', 'Multi-Family'],
  'listing_information_date_updated': '11/03/2017',
  'lot_size': ['1620', 'sqft'],
  'neighborhood': 'Marina',
  'overview': ['Multi-Family',
               '2 Beds',
               'Built in 1908',
               '1 days on Trulia',
               '1620 sqft lot size',
               '2,524 sqft',
               '$711/sqft'],
  'prices': ['$850,000', '$1,350,000', '$1,200,000'],
  'public_records': ['1 Bathroom',
                     'Multi-Family',
                     '1,296 Square Feet',
                     'Lot Size: 1,620 sqft'],
  'public_records_date_updated': '07/01/2017',
  'url': 'https://www.trulia.com/property/1072559047-1860-Lombard-St-San-Francisco-CA-94123'}]
```

where the `lot_size` field is a list with the number and the unit. However, I'd ideally like to extract the unit (acres or sqft) to a separate field `lot_size_units`. I could do this by first loading the item and doing my own processing, but I was wondering whether there is a more Scrapy-native way to 'unpack' the matched groups into different items?

(I've perused the `get_value` method on [https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/129421c7e31b89b9b0f9c5f7d8ae59e47df36091/scrapy/loader/**init**.py](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/129421c7e31b89b9b0f9c5f7d8ae59e47df36091/scrapy/loader/__init__.py), but this hasn't 'shown me the way' yet if there is any).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this (ignoring one group at a time):

```
overview.add_xpath('lot_size', xpath='.//li/text()', re=r'([\d,]+) (?:acres|sqft) lot size$')
overview.add_xpath('lot_size_units', xpath='.//li/text()', re=r'(?:[\d,]+) (acres|sqft) lot size$')
```

Comment: I realize this, but it is not DRY because you are essentially repeating the same regular expression but with different groups. I guess what I am envisaging is an `xpath` API which accepts a tuple as the `field_name` argument and 'unpacks' to this list the multiple groups matched in the regular expression.

Comment: You're right, but like someone wise already said "premature optimization is the root of all evil". I don't see anything in the html source that could help you to distinguish each part (unless they are always fixed positions), the only other alternative would be to perform all the extraction outside the `ItemLoader` using externally a regex (just like the it's done by the `ItemLoader`) and use the `add_value` methods to add each field, but that is probably more error prone than the current solution. Other alternatives like using regexes inside the xpath would have the same outcome.